# What are the phonological rules or constraints for these pairs of words?

Tags: phonology, vowels, theoretical-linguistics

Mongol-Mongolia
Arab-Arabia
Babylon-Babylonian
Boston-Bostonian
comedy-comedian
colony-colonial

I know that the vowel in the second syllable is lengthened, but what are the rules or constraints for the lengthening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of rule (20b), p. 181 of Chomsky & Halle 1968 *The sound pattern of English*, colloquially known as "Abelian lengthening". By that rule, a non-high vowel becomes tense (that was later reanalyzed as length) before one consonant followed by an unstressed front vocoid in turn followed by a vowel (i.e. before CĭV).

Comment: But notice that there is a contrary rule as well (though it is somewhat unpredictable. [Trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) is the name for the process in _satire_ -> _satirical_, _insane_ -> _insanity_, _cone_ -> _conical_.

Comment: @user6726 Thank you for your reply. May I ask one more question? What does the C1 with the footnote 1 in the rule (20b) mean?

Comment: That means "between 1 (the subscript) and 1 (the superscript) consonant", i.e. "exactly one". It is a complete mystery why they did not just write that as "C", which means the same thing.